# Как передать виджет в модель?

Tags: php, yii

Я использую виджет для выполнения какой либо операции с текстом. И эта операция должна проводиться в beforeSave(). Ну или придумать что-то другое.
Это виджет.

```
<?php
require_once('/../EMT.php');

class lnEMTypograph extends CWidget
{
    public $text;

    public function init()
        {
            parent::init();
        }

    public function run()
    {
        $typograph = new EMTypograph();
        $typograph->setup([
            'Text.paragraphs' => 'off',
            'OptAlign.oa_quote' => 'off',
        ]);
        $typograph->set_text($text);
        $text = $typograph->apply();

        echo $text;

        $this->render($text);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Имхо не очень хорошее решение использовать widget в модельке так как они предназначены для того чтобы их использовали во view. Кроме того widget должен генерировать некую разметку, а в вашем же случае widget выполняет форматирование текста. Я бы сделал некий помощник в виде класса со статическим методом.

Пример помощника

```
class TypographHelper {
    public static function apply($text) {
        $typograph = new EMTypograph();
        $typograph->setup([
            'Text.paragraphs' => 'off',
            'OptAlign.oa_quote' => 'off',
        ]);
        $typograph->set_text($text);
        return $typograph->apply();
    }
}
```

Затем в модельке используете его:

```
class ... extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public function beforeSave($insert){
        if (parent::beforeSave($insert)) {           
            $this->text = TypographHelper::apply($this->text);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Вот у меня глупый вопрос. В хелпере можно использовать require_once('/../EMT.php'); или есть какие то, более правильный способ добавить нужный файл?

Comment: Используйте пространства имен